# How to make nodejs server act like a proxy and get img from cloudinary then send it to browser

Tags: node.js, express, axios, nodejs-server, node.js-stream

for storage space issues i cannot save images in server so i had to store it in cloudinary
and for seo purposes I had to serve it from my domain not cloudinary's
so i thought to get img files from cloudinary and send it directly to browser (to be served from my domain name )
what i am missing is converting the img file i got from cloudinary api into the right form so i can send it using response object in nodejs
here is the code

```js
app.get('/uploads/img/:imgName', (req, res) => {
    axios.get('https://res.cloudinary.com/dkhccaa25/image/upload/blog_img/${req.params.imgName}')
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    /* how to convert response into the right format so it can be sent */
    //
    //
    //
})
.then (response => {
    /*converted response */
    res.sendFile(response)

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

how I can be able to send the file from node server to browser so it can be displayed using
`<img src="img url...">`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found this solution.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();

app.get('/media', (req, res) => {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: req.query.media,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
  .then((result) => {
     res
       .header("content-type", result.headers['content-type'])
       .send(Buffer.from(result.data, 'binary')
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use res.sendFile, this will require saving it to the filesystem.  Basically - accept the response and pass it directly with the correct content-type header send by the upstream response to the client.

Minimal example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('https://static.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg').then((axiosResp) => {
    res.header('content-type', axiosResp.headers['content-type']).send(axiosResp.data);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: thanks dear for your answer , but unfortunately it didn't work as i expected,   the rendered image in the browser is just a small square,  the full image not rendered

Answer (score 0):

finally the problem solved by editing on @madflow answer (thanks for him )

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('https://static.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg', {responseType: 'stream'})
.then((axiosResp) => {
     res.set({
       'Content-Type': axiosResp.headers['content-type']
     })
     axiosResp.data.pipe(res)

  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```